# Unknown __lldb_autogen_pair type in Debugger Output

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking, lldb

I'm loading JSON from server, and found very strange type name, and don't know what to do 
with this [image]

What does `struct _lldb_autogen_pair` mean, and why is it there, when the JSON is:

Original:

```
{
"2011.10.06": [
  {
    "place":"home",
    "role":0,
    "title":"abc"
  }
],
}
```

**UPDATE**
I have a singleton subclass of AFHTTPRequestOperationManager, so i make

```
client = [[VZWebClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kVZWebClientHostName]];
client.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
```

in NSLOG that's all ok without any surpises

Comment: i guess it is just for display purpose

Comment: Why did some of them shows normal, while others with this sign ? May be wrong data from server or structure trouble ?

Comment: it is more likely Xcode implementatino details somehow leaked to you. you can just ignore it.

Comment: It looks to me like you're not using NSJSONSerialization to parse the JSON, but are using some Jacksonesque parser to return object instances.  And so it's returned an instance of __libd_autogen_nspair.

Comment: (Either that or the debugger is going bonkers as usual.  Never trust the debugger -- do NSLog or use `po myJSONObject` in the console window.)

Comment: i'm updated my question, so i think it's debugger problem

Comment: @HotLicks "Never trust the debugger" is not great advice. I'd encourage you to take the time to understand the tool. It's quite powerful if you know how to use it.

Comment: @mattt - Powerful, perhaps, but, when it comes to displaying data, untrustworthy.

Comment: @HotLicks It's not a matter of trust. It's a matter of understanding. Data does not have one single, inherent representation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking at the contents of an NSDictionary. The container is logically made up of key ==> value pairs.

However, if you go look at the in-memory representation of the dictionary, it is just storing a sequence of object pointers, e.g. something like

```
0x123 (key)
0x456 (value)
0x356 (key)
0x577 (value)
...
```

If you're LLDB, you need to find a way to group each key with its value. In C++, it's an easy problem because you have std::pair<> that you can use (and C++ std::map<> tends to use that type internally to store the entries anyway, so you get the grouping for free). In ObjC, you need something that lets you make that grouping happen.

So what we do is generate a fake type __lldb_autogen_nspair, which essentially boils down to

```
struct __lldb_autogen_nspair { id key; id value; };
```

and we present NSDictionary as a container of those structs.

The name is pretty much meant to say "hey this is an LLDB implementation detail, don't worry about it".

Comment: Thanks for little theory course, it's what i'm asking for!

Answer (score 2):

`__lldb_autogen_pair` is a private data type used as an intermediary representation of `NSDictionary` key/value pairs by the [LLDB debugger](http://lldb.llvm.org). This is not actually a part of that value, but something generated by the debugger to allow you to inspect it in that interface.

Double-underscore (`__`) prefixes conventionally denote a private type, and is something you shouldn't usually have to worry about.